# Get Values of Multiple Select Dropdowns in Group Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select dropdowns as such:

```
<select name="offer1cards[]">
    <option value="1">Card 1</option>
    <option value="2">Card 2</option>
    <option value="3">Card 3</option>
</select>
<select name="offer1cards[]">
    <option value="1">Card 1</option>
    <option value="2">Card 2</option>
    <option value="3">Card 3</option>
</select>
<select name="offer1cards[]">
    <option value="1">Card 1</option>
    <option value="2">Card 2</option>
    <option value="3">Card 3</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get the values into a comma separated string using jquery but I know I am not doing something right:

```
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='offer1cards[]']:selected"), function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
    var items = values.split(',');
    alert(items);
});
```

How can I get these values into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily using `:selected` and instead of `split` use `join` to join a array, Just do

```
var values = new Array(), var items;
$.each($("input[name='offer1cards[]']"), function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
items = values.join(',');
alert(items);
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I just needed to change `input` to `select` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You `$.map()` them and then `.join()` 'em.

```
var res = $.map($("select[name='offer1cards[]']"), function(ele) {
        return $(ele).val();
    }).join(', ');

    alert(res);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5t9ddd98/1/